# Combining fields from two queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here are the two tables I'm working with:

NBAGameLog:

```
Player_ID, Team, Minutes, Date_Played
```

Players:

```
Player_ID, First Name, Last Name, Position
```

I have these two queries right now:

AvgMP15:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position, NBAGameLog.Tm, ROUND(AVG(AvgMP1),2) AS AvgMP
FROM (SELECT Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position, NBAGameLog.Tm, ROUND(AVG(NBAGameLog.MP),2) As AvgMP1
FROM NBAGameLog INNER JOIN Players ON NBAGameLog.Player_ID = Players.Player_ID
WHERE (((NBAGameLog.Date_Played) Between Date()-15 And Date()))
GROUP BY NBAGameLog.Date_Played, Players.Position, NBAGameLog.FD_Points, Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, NBAGameLog.Tm, Players.Player_ID)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
GROUP BY Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position, NBAGameLog.Tm;
```

AvgMP:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW p.FirstName, p.LastName, gl.Tm, ROUND(Avg(gl.MP),2) AS AvgMPS
FROM NBAGameLog AS gl INNER JOIN Players AS p ON gl.Player_ID = p.Player_ID
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, gl.Tm
ORDER BY Avg(gl.MP) DESC;
```

The first one gives me a player's name, position, team and his average minutes played from the last 15 games.

The second one gives me his averave minutes played for the entire season.

I want to compare these two, so I'd like a query that pulls:

First Name, Last Name, Position, Team, Minutes Played in the Last 15, Minutes played the whole season, Difference between 15 and season.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to show an example table so we can help you :)

Comment: I think your first query gets average minutes for any games played in the last 15 days, not the last 15 games, is that what you want?  If a player hasn't played in last 15 games, s/he won't be in the first query, do you want her/him in the consolidated query?

Comment: Excellent points! I added the table structure to my original question (hopefully that's enough detail).

Also, you're correct Levin, it's just the last 15 days, regardless of if that player played or not. So if one player only had 4 games in those 15 days, those are the only games that are displayed. But the player should be in both queries (they'd just have 0 for the last 15)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW p.FirstName, p.LastName, gl.Tm, ROUND(Avg(gl.MP),2) AS Season, ROUND(Avg(gl2.MP),2) AS Last15, ROUND((Last15-Season),2) AS Diff
FROM (NBAGameLog AS gl INNER JOIN Players AS p ON gl.Player_ID = p.Player_ID) INNER JOIN NBAGameLog AS gl2 ON gl2.Player_ID = gl.Player_ID
WHERE gl2.Date_Played Between Date()-15 And Date()
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, gl.Tm
ORDER BY p.LastName;
```